# How do I control axis limits in Plots.jl such that axis starts and ends at a tick?

Tags: plots.jl

Only `using Plots`, how do I control axis limits? I want that the axis always starts and ends at a tick, not the default expansion by some small space. I couldn't find anything useful in `plotattr(:Series)`.

Code is the standard example:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10);
plot(x,y)
```

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that

```
plot!(
      xlims=(floor(minimum(x)),ceil(maximum(x))), 
      ylims=(floor(minimum(y)),ceil(maximum(y)))
     )
```

does the trick.